# Copy Active Cell to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a selected cell values only to another sheet. The Selected cell varies but will always be placed in Sheet1 ("A9")

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to use `Selection` (even though it's recommended to stay away from it), then use the code below:

```
Sub CopyPaste_toA9()

Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A9").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subroutine to do just that:

```
Sub copy_cell(CopyFrom As Range, CopyTo As Range)
    CopyTo.Value = CopyFrom.Value
End Sub
```

And call it like so:

```
Sub testing()
    Dim CopyFrom As Range
    Dim CopyTo As Range
    Set CopyFrom = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    Set CopyTo = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A9")
    Call copy_cell(CopyFrom, CopyTo)
End Sub
```